# Django REST Framework. Keep getting KeyError in all the methods

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After some time of testing my Django REST Api i started to get KeyError when using request.data. The problem didn't occured before that, it just randomly started to happen. Im using Python 3.8 and Django REST 3.11

Here are my serializers and views. I'll appreciate any help.

serializers.py

```
class InterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Interest
        fields = '__all__'

class UserIntrestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest = InterestSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserInterest
        fields = ('id','interest')
```

views.py

```
class UserInterestView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserIntrestSerializer

    def get_user_interests(self, request):
        try:
            user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.data['id'])
            interests = UserInterest.objects.all().filter(user__id = user.id)
            serializer = UserIntrestSerializer(interests, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            return Response("No data given", status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def create_user_interests(self, request):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data['id'])
            interest_list = [Interest.objects.all().filter(name=interest)[0] for interest in request.data['interests']]
            print(interest_list)
            for interest in interest_list:
                UserInterest(user=user, interest=interest).save()
            return Response("User interests created properly")
        except IndexError:
            return Response("Interest not found", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response("User not found")

    def delete_interest(self, request):
        try:
            userinterest = UserInterest.objects.get(interest__name=request.data["interest_name"], user__id=request.data["user_id"])
            userinterest.delete()
            return Response("User's interest deleted properly", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except UserInterest.DoesNotExist:
            return Response("User or User's interest not found", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def update_interest(self, request):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data['id'])
            current_interests = [user_interest.interest for user_interest in UserInterest.objects.all().filter(user__id=user.id)]
            new_interests = [Interest.objects.get(name=interest) for interest in request.data['new_interests']]

            for current_interest in current_interests:
                if current_interest not in new_interests:
                    UserInterest.objects.get(user=user, interest=current_interest).delete()
            for new_interest in new_interests:
                if new_interest not in current_interests:
                    UserInterest(interest=new_interest, user=user).save()
            return Response("Interests updated properly", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response("User or User's interests haven't been found", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        except KeyError:
            return Response("ID or new_interests haven't been provided", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am using Postman for my requests.

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

GET request has no body (`data`) that is why `request.data` isn't working. You could send the `id` in the url and use `request.GET['id']`

ex: `https://yourdomain.com/?id=2`

Comment: What if i want to send data using request's body?